# Relatively new Windows 10 laptop suddenly started getting random BSOD after 3 months of flawless use

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bsod, crash, nvidia-graphics-card

Lately, I've been having some issues with my laptop. I got it in March and it worked perfectly all the way to June. Around 10 days ago, it has started to suddenly crash for seemingly no reason at all. There doesn't seem to be anything in particular triggering the crash, except maybe having a lot of tabs open in Firefox, maybe.

The laptop is an ASUS TUF Gaming FX505 DT. The most recent crash report from the Reliability Monitor is:

"The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x000000ea (0xffff860e2b3680c0, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: fd4fc8c3-51d7-48ff-b789-bccd21a7f7dc."

According to the reliability report, the following applications updated in June 19th's night, right before the first crash:

2020-05 Microsoft Edge Update for Windows 10 Version 1903 for x64-based Systems (KB4559309)
9NF8H0H7WMLT-NVIDIACorp.NVIDIAControlPanel

Could either of this updates have caused the issue? Anything I should check? Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Have you worked it out?

Comment: Consider reinstalling Windows, that will let you know if its software or hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest you restart your machine with all unneeded items removed,
External hard disks, USB thumbnail drives, etc.

*Note that there is a lot of Rebooting to these processes.*

First create a shortcut on your desktop for a Command Prompt (CMD.EXE).
After you create the shortcut, right-click on it and choose "Advanced"
in the "Shortcut" tab and check the box for Run as administrative mode.

1. **Run Windows Disk Checker (Check Disk)**

Open the Command Prompt and type or paste the command:

CHKDSK /F C:

(C: for Windows partition, if your drive letter is different replace the
letter with the correct letter). Press "Y" to confirm the disk is to be checked
when you reboot/restart/start the machine. Then close the Command Prompt and reboot.

Do not press any keys and let it run, it will again reboot the machine
before it loads Windows, especially if it finds and fixes any errors.

Note: If for any chance it gets stuck in a loop (Restarting, Restarting...)
then by all means press the ENTER key when Checkdisk asks.

2. **Run a System File Check (SFC)**

When it reboots don't open anything, and the less your move your mouse the better.

Open the Command Prompt with the shortcut and type SFC /SCANNOW and let
this run completely. This will check for any changes in system files it might be
able to fix or repair.

After this is finished you should again reboot your machine.

Let the machine load for about 15 minutes without opening any applications
such as notepad, or other softwares, especially online browsers.

3. **Start Component Cleanup**

When your machine is up and has been Idle, try running
"Deployment Image Servicing and Management" (DISM) from the Command Prompt
you created. Type or paste in the following:
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

Then Reboot Again.

4. **Run DISM for the Last Time**

When your machine is up and has been Idle, try running
"Deployment Image Servicing and Management" (DISM) from the Command Prompt
you created. Type or paste in the following:
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

Be patient, it may take quiet a while to finish.

Then again, reboot your machine.

**INFORMATION ON THE DISM COMMAND**

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

/Online - This tell the tool you are online and ready for Windows update, etc. to help

/Cleanup-image - Used for cleanup and recovery operations on the running Operating System.

/Restorehealth - This command checks for corruption and fixes them automatically.

**My sources online you may want to visit:**

Note that in most ((docs.Microsoft.com)) pages you can download a .pdf file, (lower left column).

"Clean Up the WinSxS Folder"

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder

"Repair a Windows Image"

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image

"Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files"

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=717888

"DISM Operating System Package Servicing Command-Line Options"

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-operating-system-package-servicing-command-line-options

Comment: PSH, fire up a Linux ISO from Ram would be my step one, poke around a bit.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers The user is relatively new to the games Windows plays so I cannot advise that. Thanks.

Comment: The less you move your mouse the better? .... Skeptical

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Try Process Monitor(?), have it point to the registry and run your mouse around the desktop.... There are also other softwares out there which shows how mouse movement can slow you down. Good Day