# How to stop explorer.exe from crashing

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, start-menu

I am running windows 10 may 2004 x64. And whenever I click on start menu my explorer.exe crashes and restarts. How do I stop it from doing so.

I updated to latest version using MediaCreation.

I have this problem from the point I updated windows to the latest version

I have not changed Start Menu layout so it is not the problem.

I noticed that I don't have explorer folder in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows"

I am not able to search anything from explorer and taskbar.

I tried sfc /scannow,  chkdsk, and dism commands but no result from these.

---

***I am attaching the error log from reliability test***

**Source**

Windows Explorer

**Summary**

Stopped working

**Date**

‎7/‎1/‎2020 10:03 AM

**Status**

Report sent

**Description**

Faulting Application Path:  C:\Windows\explorer.exe

**Problem signature**

Problem Event Name: APPCRASH

Application Name:   Explorer.EXE

Application Version:    10.0.19041.329

Application Timestamp:  b584d6c9

Fault Module Name:  twinui.pcshell.dll

Fault Module Version:   10.0.19041.329

Fault Module Timestamp: 1da0a9bb

Exception Code: c0000005

Exception Offset:   0000000000085ced

OS Version: 10.0.19041.2.0.0.256.4

Locale ID:  1033

Additional Information 1:   1908

Additional Information 2:   190818e837de5133bf9a0aa7e10d0298

Additional Information 3:   31dc

Additional Information 4:   31dcb4a07afdabfd4b606b1ea3c18e90

**Extra information about the problem**

Bucket ID:  83ee0748e1e844ab4f4fd3658c59b2fd (2256254371435754237)

Comment: Have you performed any cleanup on your computer lately? May be you should please see my last post here https://superuser.com/questions/1565181/relatively-new-windows-10-laptop-suddenly-started-getting-random-bsod-after-3-mo/1565194#1565194

Comment: No,  but I tried sfc /scannow, chkdsk, and dism commands but no result

Comment: I read your post and have tried these but no luck and for recovery and reset I have many files that I cannot backup right now so no luck on that too.

Comment: Have you made any changes using the Local Security Policy or Group Policy Editor(s)? If so, you may need to check out changes you have made and maybe reverse them. Put all to defaults.

Comment: I have not made any changes but if you can help about how to reset these policies it would be nice.

Comment: I tried RestoreHealth again then it worked for me but after restart it started crashing again

Comment: Try creating a new user profile and login using the new user.. does it happen in that profile?  If it doesn't then your current user registry is corrupt.  If it does, then there is probably a shell extension loaded that is doing it.

Comment: Creating new user worked. And please check this question https://superuser.com/questions/1567257/how-to-repair-corrupt-user-registry-keys . I have problem with maybe registry as you said. Do post your answer on this question so that I can mark it. @Señor CMasMas

Answer (score -1):

These are solutions and fixes-:

> 1.Delete all registry keys in \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local
> Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell
>
> Expand "Shell" and deleted both "BagMRU" and "Bag" keys.Do not worry
> as they rebuild after restart
>
> 2.Clear History of File explorer by click on Start-File explorer-File explorer options.In privacy settings click clear

3.Change Display Resolution of Monitor

**4.Uninstall and Reinstall your graphics driver it by device manager.Check your graphic card vendor to see if any update released for your product**

> 5.Enable launch Folder in Windows in a Separate Process by Start-File Explorer options-View-Launch folder windows in a separate
> process"-Apply and Ok

6.Disable your antivirus if installed

7.Try Netsh Winsock Reset to fix any socket errors that malicious script on the computer or unknown file

8.Try booting in Safe Mode of Windows and check whether issue persists

9.If the issue dont persist in Safe Mode then some startup program is causing interrupt and causing problem

Boot in normal mode type msconfig in search and open msconfig and untick load startup items

[image]

Then Go to startup tab and hide all non-microsoft services and then click disable all

[image]

Click apply and Ok and reboot

**10.If all fails do a clean installation of windows again**

Note:The images I uploaded settings of my PC not from any website

Source:
https://www.easeus.com/resource/how-to-fix-windows-10-file-explorer-keeps-crashing.html

I did not copy from them just got the idea from website so it will be unfair not to give regards to them.

Comment: I tried above options but no progress and when booting to safe mode it was not gone

Comment: There was a update to my graphics card but the problem is still there

Comment: Do a clean re-installation of windows

Comment: I think then I will let the problem be there for some time because at the moment I will not be able to clean install windows (no backup media lmao)

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-start-menu-keeps-crashing-upon/93181e22-f198-4970-afc1-c8cde7aa49f8
this thread has exact same problem, so maybe something like a windows bug.

Comment: This answer has verbatim sentences, copied directly from the resource link, without a single quotation.  Even though some of the sentences are only section headers, it does not matter, those are not your words.  Please quote and cite any resources you might be using.  **You must make it clear are your own words.**