# What is ".ESD_" file and how to use it

Tags: windows-10, media-creation-tool

I have this "19041.264.200511-0456.vb_release_svc_refresh_CLIENTBUSINESS_VOL_x64FRE_en-us.ESD_" file in Windows10Upgrade folder. How to use this file to create own installer media.

My drive has Windows10Upgrade folder at 2 locations :-

1. At default C drive
2. At another partition (E drive) (I have above file in this folder.)

Comment: Why do you want to use this file instead of just using the Media Creation Tool?

Comment: Because I am on limited net connection and creating iso would consume my internt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ESD, Electronic Software Download, file is an encrypted file used for Windows installation as stated [here](https://www.lifewire.com/esd-file-2621103):

> so the file itself is called a Windows Electronic Software Download file. An ESD file stores an encrypted Windows Imaging Format (.WIM) file.

Your PC has downloaded (or is downloading) that the file(s) to upgrade Windows. But they could also be used to reset your PC as described [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-esd-file-iso-windows/):

> These ESD files are used for “resetting your PC” to its factory default settings. If you delete these files, you’ll have more disk space–but you won’t have the files necessary to reset your PC. You may need to download Windows 10 installation media if you ever want to reset it.

Comment: Sorry but I am asking about ".esd_" file not ".esd"

Comment: When windows is ready to use the file, it will remove the `-`.

Comment: But its like this file is like this for a few weeks now but no changes and I want to clean install windows 10 due to some problem (check my other question https://superuser.com/questions/1565189/how-to-stop-explorer-exe-from-crashing/1565306)

Comment: Try to check if window updates are available. If yes, update your system. That might also help for your other question.

Comment: Checked them, no solution but clean install I think would work, so during this limited connection using these old installer files would work. If any help on ".esd_" file please help.  Can I just rename the extension and use as above mentioned.

Comment: I am not sure if that is advisable or not. But you can ask another question about it. Other forum members will be able to advise on it.

Comment: I find no mention of the_ after ESD anywhere, just copy the file to another folder and rename it, then try to use it, ESD can also be converted to ISO format>>>>>>https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-turn-your-windows-10-upgrade-into-an-iso/