# How to repair corrupt user registry keys?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, start-menu

I have Windows 10 2004 x64 update and in recent few weeks there was some problem with my Start Menu. With help from this platform I figured out that it was due to my current user account.

**So how do I repair that old user account registries ?**

Link to main question ( [How to stop explorer.exe from crashing](https://superuser.com/questions/1565189/how-to-stop-explorer-exe-from-crashing) )

Comment: Do you know which registry paths or keys were changed?

Comment: First insert the installation media of windows 10 (like a CD or DVD or any USB drive) and sender BIOS or UEFI settings. Go to the boot tab and set the boot priority of media to first. Now boot from it and choose Troubleshoot. Then you can perform a System Restore or Reset your PC with keep files option. Before that, boot into windows 10 and run `sfc /scannow`. Then run Windows image recovery with `dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth`. You can also perform a clean re-installlation of windows 10. If you know anyone who has a windows 10 PC, export his entire registry and merge it in your PC.

Comment: No, I don't know which paths were changed. And for the sfc /scannow and dism command I have tried them earlier and it did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the user accounts. Seriously

This is, by far, the simplest means of repairing the registry for a user account.

1. Create a new user account and make sure it does not have the same issues.
2. Copy your data to the new user account.
3. Delete the old user account.

If you want to use the same user account name as previously, do this process one more time, creating new user account with your desired username and copy the data to it.

Comment: But I tried it and the shortcuts just broke for the users.

Comment: Ok, then how about you tell us what problem you were trying to fix when you messed up your registry.

Comment: Nothing, I just upgraded windows to May 2020 update using update assistant and then the Start Menu started  hanging and now whenever I open start menu explorer crashes. (Refer to other question https://superuser.com/questions/1565189/how-to-stop-explorer-exe-from-crashing )