# Windows search not working

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-search

My start menu search and explorer search is not working. It is working normally in a test user account.

I had problem with start menu earlier too but after this cumulative update it was resolved. ( [How to stop explorer.exe from crashing](https://superuser.com/questions/1565189/how-to-stop-explorer-exe-from-crashing) )

But the search problem still persists.

I am using Windows 10 x64 2004 updated to KB4565503 (2020-07 cumulative update)

Comment: "My start menu search and explorer search is not working. It is working normally in a test user account."  <-- This would appear that your user profile is corrupted. Repairs and Upgrades will not fix a damaged profile. You need to save the data, make a new profile, restore the data and delete the broken profile.

Comment: After what cumulative update?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it again and I cannot probably change user because when changing user account the copied shortcuts don't work well.

Comment: You need to remake the shortcuts when you change user profiles. It is a fairly big job.

Comment: Yeah I know, so can you post this as the answer that how to do user profile and shortcuts.